# Not able to set up firebase admob for cocos2dx 3.17

Tags: android, firebase, admob, cocos2d-x

I want to integrate Firebase Admob in cocos2dx. I am getting error

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/…/…/…/…/i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lfirebase_feature
```

I am referring the link https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-v3-17-and-firebase-c-sdk/45596 who also getting same error. Could you please let us know what should be solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by updating CMakeLists.txt file : with

```
add_subdirectory(${FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR} bin/ EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
   set(FIREBASE_SDK_LIBDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/firebase_cpp_sdk/libs/android/${ANDROID_ABI}/c++)
set(libfirebase_admob libfirebase_app)

target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} ${FIREBASE_SDK_LIBDIR}/libfirebase_admob.a)
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} ${FIREBASE_SDK_LIBDIR}/libfirebase_app.a)
```